# How can I enable CORS?

Tags: java, angularjs, cors, httpresponse

I need activate CORS for cross-domain request from my web to my java server in Apache Tomcat (7.0.52).

I use GET, PUT, OPTIONS and POST methods with AngularJS. For example:

```
$http.get("http://domainWithTomcat.net/javaAppName/api/Picking").success(function (result) {
    $scope.recepcionesPicking = result;
    $scope.startPagination();
});
```

Thats my web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        es.rumbosistemas.sctrakker.datos.HibernateContextListenerAndFilter
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>HibernateContextListenerAndFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>es.rumbosistemas.sctrakker.datos.HibernateContextListenerAndFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HibernateContextListenerAndFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>FilterSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FilterSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/Application/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The console log thows me this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domainWithTomcat.net/javaAppName/api/Picking. The request was redirected to 'http://domainWeb.com/Login/index.html', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

And, the headers of request and response are this:

Request headers

```
OPTIONS /APP/api/Session HTTP/1.1
Host: domainWithTomcat.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://www.myWeb.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.myWeb.com/web/Login/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://myWeb.net/myAppClient/Login/index.html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=52886875C222C5E276FBFCB9CED1517F; Path=/SCTM/; HttpOnly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=6c6b3d5a9861fd850ca4be11e8881705c4f3156c038ab6ca4f4a57a798d12b9b;Path=/;Domain=tomcatDomain.com
Date: Mon, 17 Nov 2014 08:06:11 GMT
```

My tomcat are in Azure, for if important...

Ok, thanks to maslan now I can login but I have another issue. 
When I make a new request the server doesn't put the session and creates a new session so my filter detects as if I'm not logged and the request fails. Any idea?
I can see the session that has the username as session variable in Tomcat. But for every request I make, creates a new session. As if the client does not keep coockies ... I dont know

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Can you please look in your browser's developer tools and log the response?

Comment: Added the console log and the headers. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Well this is working as specified. http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0 . Http status 302 must be dealt with as a network error.

Comment: Can you add this to your Angular application $.ajaxSetup({ xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, crossDomain: true }); I had similar problem, I think, but I'm not sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Spring MVC, and the Dispatcher Servlet is by default configured to intercept OPTIONS. You need to configure it in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup></servlet>
```

Comment: With this I can login, its something! But now I have a new issue, when I make a new request the server doesn't put the session and creates a new session so my filter detects as if I'm not logged and the request fails. Any idea?

Comment: Why do You need session in OPTIONS?

Answer (score 0):

## check the [cors-filter](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html)

### downloud cors-filter-2.1.2.jar java-property-utils-1.9.1.jar

mvn dependecy

`<dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-property-utils</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>`

and in web.xml

`<filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>`